# How to update Unity?

Tags: unity

I have clicked on *check for updates* but it says I have latest Unity.

But latest is 5.6.

How to update it to 5.6?

[image]

Comment: Go to unity3d.com and hit "Get Unity" then download the installer for the latest version.

Comment: Yeah, the built-in Unity update check is...weird. I've seen it say "you need to download the new version" for about a second, then apparently change its mind and say "Unity is up to date" a moment later. @Almo, even though the answer may be trivial, I think it's worth posting as an answer since it does correctly answer the question. Maybe also mention that you can scroll to the bottom of the page to "Already Own Unity? --> Download" to skip selecting a subscription plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem here. As **Almo** said, you need to download Unity again.

Unity 5.5 can't update to Unity 5.6

If you download the new version and put to install in the same folder it will replace the older version.

Comment: But latest in 5.5 version is 5.5.2 and I have 5.5.0. so it does not update correctly.

Comment: When I opened Unity yesterday just appear a screen asking if I wanna update from 5.5.0 to 5.6.1

When I click to confirm, it redirected me to Unity website to download the new version.

Seems it is just the way it works...